# Are there any decent online undergrad computer science degrees or courses

Tags: distance-learning, online-learning

To keep it short I already have a BS and MS in a physical science from decent schools.  I want to apply next year for a MS or PhD in ECE and thought I should get some formal programming on my transcript first.  I have only one intro class on there now.

I'm not having much luck finding any online courses that don't look like scams or poorly set up at best.  I was pretty excited to see that [Oregon state](http://eecs.oregonstate.edu/new-online-post-baccalaureate-computer-science-degree) is offering a post-bacc BS degree but the tuition is $600 a credit.

So I guess I'm looking for legitimate courses that aren't crazy expensive.  Is there anything else out there like the Oregon state program?  That's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I think Oregon State's tuition is pretty typical.  My department charges about $2000 for each of its online course.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to try Coursera. [Their courses](https://www.coursera.org/courses) are quite good and the instructors are some of the top computer scientists in their fields.

They give you a certificate signed by the instructor if you finish the course well.

Comment: Thanks.  I worked through a bit of the machine learning course and thought it was really well done.  I'm worried I need to more formal classes to get accepted to a grad program.  Maybe I'm wrong though.

Comment: @user21975, I don't think you can find anything better *online*. At least these are by well-known instructors.

Comment: @user21975  
Your reference letters will matter way more than whether you have an extra coding course on your transcript or not. I earned a BS and MS in math, before enrolling in a PhD in CS. When I applied, I had no formal training in hardware. In my application, I promised that if I was admitted, I would take an undergrad course in that area (which I did my first year in the PhD program). For your PhD application though, your letters of rec (and who they come from) matter more than almost anything else.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this [tool](http://www.distancelearning.com/degrees/computers-and-it/) and refine your search, and also checkout this [article](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/01/10/the-top-online-colleges-u_n_1194479.html) from Huffington Post.

~Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to Ac.sx! It would be useful if you could expand your answer and not just provide the links, see the [faq](http://academia.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion) otherwise there is a risk your answer might be closed.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the reminder. I'm new here--and yay don't want my answer to be closed. btw guys, Coding for Good cfg(dot)good(dot)is is also interesting. Then again thanks, Peter! See you around :)